# Using xmlhttp.open() how do I add more than one parameter to url?

Tags: ajax, variables, get, xmlhttprequest

I have this code.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);

where q="+str
```

I want to pass a second var how do I do this?

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q=" + q + "&r=" + r, true);
```

Note that this will not properly escape your parameters if they contains special characters. You might want to use something like `encodeURIComponent(q)` instead.

Comment: dude. this helped me sooooo much. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Append `+ "&anotherVar=" + anotherString`.