# PHP & MYSQL Database Insertion Blank

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

OK so I am new to php,ajax and mysql and I have searched the forum trying everything but still nothing..I know it's some simple mistake but as it stands my code is entering blank info into the database through my forms but when I type the string directly in the query it appears in the database, please help me

PS I know it might not be the most secure code but that's not the issue at hand

```
                  function message(){


    alert("You are about to compose a message");
    var stuff=[
        '<div id ="compose_window">',
        '<div id="new_message">',
        '<div id="header"><strong> New Message </strong></div>',
        '</div>',

    '<form action="" method= "post">',
    '<fieldset>',
    '<strong>To</strong><br> <input type="text" id ="recipient" name="recipient" class="textfield"> <br>',
    '<strong>Subject</strong><br> <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="textfield"> <br><br>',
    '<strong>Message</strong><br> <textarea  id = "content" name="content" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea> <br>',
    '<button id="send" type="button" onclick= loadXMLDoc()> <strong> Send </strong> </button>',
    '</fieldset>',
        '</form>',
        '</div>',
        '<div id="Response"></div>',

    ].join('');

    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML= stuff;




}
    function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("ajaxResponse").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","send.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and this is the php for the insertion

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("127.9.52.129","boballen","","cheapomail");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO messages (subject, recipient_ids, body)
VALUES
('$_POST[subject]','$_POST[recipient]','$_POST[content]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "Message Sent 1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: it means your data is not coming in POST variable

Answer (score 3):

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, please use prepared statements or escape the variables before using them in the query. The reason, why you get empty row when inserting, is this:

you are using $_POST array in your query, while sending the data through GET request in Ajax:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","send.php",true);
```

use $_GET instead of $_POST:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO messages (subject, recipient_ids, body)
VALUES (?,?,?)";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $_GET['subject'],$_GET['recipient'],
                      $_GET['content']);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

### Ajax

You are also not sending GET parameters in Ajax request. Try adding them, using something like this:

```
subject = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("subject").value);
recipient = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("recipient").value);
content = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("content").value);
xmlhttp.open("GET","send.php?subject=" + subject + "&recipient=" 
             + recipient + "&content=" + content,true);
```

Where you get subject, recipient and content variables from the appropriate inputs on your page.

Comment: @Nick What if something comes through POST? $_REQUEST is more versatile

Comment: Depending on your PHP setup, $_REQUEST can also pick up $_COOKIE and $_SESSION. This means it makes it much easier for someone to spoof the data, opening you up to a range of new security problems. You should always know if data is coming to your script as GET or POST (if you are getting the same data through as both GET and POST in different situations, then you're definitely doing it wrong), so there is no reason to not specify the correct method.

Comment: @Nick To strengthen security, changed to GET

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, I changes it from POST to GET and I still have blank enteries

Comment: @user3110815 Ahh, I didn't mention, that you are not sending GET parameters in your Ajax, add them, using this instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065981/using-xmlhttp-open-how-do-i-add-more-than-one-parameter-to-url. Let me know, if you can't. Will try to give you little javascript assistance.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a little over my head, would love your assistance

Comment: hmmm I added all that and now when I try to view the updated table I get an error " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '& from messages' at line 1" not really sure what's going on..just started learning all this

Comment: @user3110815 You didn't provide any code for viewing the table, so I can't tell you anything about that error. Try to view the result of insert operation, using native mysql client or phpmyadmin. Let me know, whether INSERT worked.

Comment: @user3110815 When we finish with INSERT, we can close the question and open a new one for that error. Actually, I would appreciate, if you devoted time to debug your code. It will give you some experience.

Comment: I'm using cloud9 to do all this,   inserted by using select * from messages, I'm sorry but I have been watching and reading so many tutorials about this, the teacher just started this topic so we aren't exposed to advanced techniques like "encodeURIComponent" which means it can be done in a simple way but I'm just not getting it, thanks for the help..will have to do more research

Comment: @user3110815 SELECT operator is used for getting the data from the database, it has nothing to do with INSERT. Were you able to check, whether the appropriate data is inserted by the script? If it is, we can close the question, and you can ask another one about SELECT not working. `encodeURIComponent` is used to encode & symbol in case the user puts it into the input, so it wouldn't break the code.

Comment: sorry I meant INSERT not SELECT and yes the appropriate data is being inserted and in the right columns too but only if I hard code the string to be entered, when its depending on data from form it doesn't insert

Comment: @user3110815 In this case can you explicitly call your script from browser with parameters: http://domain/send.php?subject=1&recipient=2&content=3. It must add row (1,2,3) into the table. If it doesn't, try debugging the script by printing var_dump($_GET) before you do an insert.

Comment: a friend recommended this to me early and I tried and it does work

Comment: @user3110815 In this case something is wrong with javascript. Try debugging your ajax with firebug.

Answer (score 0):

In the query use the check mark:

```
if(isset($_POST[subject]) && isset($_POST[recipient]) && isset($_POST[content])) {
$sql="INSERT INTO messages (subject, recipient_ids, body)
VALUES
('$_GET[subject]','$_GET[recipient]','$_GET[content]')";
}
```

And you are not sending any data in the `xmlhttp.send();` you need to send the data to get the data on posted page.

Comment: I tried this and the error defined in the ajax code came up, also what parameter should xmlhttp.send() have?

Comment: @user3110815 read this: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php